# PhotoBooth camera not working after upgrading to Big Sur

Tags: macos, mac

My Photobooth camera is not working after I upgraded my macOS to Big Sur. The camera is working with other apps like Skype, but with Photobooth it's showing a black screen.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of searching, I found a solution for this problem. Go to Applications folder, find icon for Photo Booth, drag while pressing Options key, make a second copy of the app. It will work. Strange, but working.